# Is my red tailed shark sick or pregnant?

Tags: fish, aquarium, freshwater

Yesterday the fishes in my tank were visually ok, today I noticed that one of my red tailed sharks has a bulky belly. Are they sick or pregnant?

Here are pictures of the two "normal" ones, and the third in question:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://animals.mom.me/signs-pregnant-redtailed-shark-9215.html

Comment: As far as Dropsy goes, there is no evidence of pine cone scales - so that might be good in a way. "Female red-tailed sharks have slightly wider bodies than males and slightly shorter fins." and http://www.myaquariumclub.com/images/fbfiles/images/xRed_Tail_Shark_1.jpg.pagespeed.ic.km_8bzvCfn.webp - do they look male or female to you? But as far as constipation goes - are blood worms good?

Comment: I feed cooked, peeled, peas to my fish if they are constipated. I was under the impression that feeding more proteinous foods like blood worm or brineshrimp increase the likely hood of constipation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think everyone's comments and links may have answered this: egg layers, so they don't show signs of pregnancy, and what to feed if it's bloat- frozen peas, defrosted and peeled first. It appears to be bloat by the way.